# Change 'from name' in Twilio message in C#

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm successfully using the Twilio API in an ASP.net C# app using the sample code (obviously changing the variables as required):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    const string authToken = "your_auth_token";
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var to = new PhoneNumber("+15017122661");
    var message = MessageResource.Create(
        to,
        from: new PhoneNumber("+15558675310"),
        body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?");

    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
}
```

I'm sure I read somewhere that you can change what the message receiver sees on their phone - so you could have 'my company' instead of the phone number the message is sent from.

However, I can't find this anywhere in Google or on the Twilio API C# samples.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is ["Alphanumeric Sender ID"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-alphanumeric-sender-id). It sounds like something associate with your twilio account and not something that is settable on a per API basis.

Comment: Thanks - that lead me to this: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133967-Changing-the-sender-ID-for-sending-SMS-messages - but I get an error: The From phone number 766227 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account. (the text i used as number is 'poobar' so it converted the text to numbers somehow by the look of it). Any ideas? Can I use any text? (I don't need the phone number to be in bound)

Comment: Is this a paid thing? If it's called 'a short code' looks like its paid and tied to an actual short phone no?

Comment: I am not an expert on twilio API and have not used it past a few free features. [This article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) is more clear on the requirements: "Alphanumeric Sender ID is automatically supported on all new upgraded (paid) Twilio accounts. It is not supported for Free Trial accounts." There are also instructions there for checking if it supported on your account. I believe short code a different concept, using a 5 or 6 digit number for the sender id.

Comment: Thanks I just needed to upgrade the account and its started working - feel free to paste into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) is more clear on the requirements. It is a paid account feature only:

> Alphanumeric Sender ID is automatically supported on all new upgraded (paid) Twilio accounts. It is not supported for Free Trial accounts.

and

> This feature is only available for upgraded (paid) Twilio accounts sending messages to supported countries. Some supported countries may have additional requirements, including pre-registration for alpha sender IDs, or limiting these messages to be only sent as transactional messages.

There are also instructions there for checking if it supported on your account. I believe short code is a different concept, using a 5 or 6 digit number for the sender id, which is also associated with larger message rate limits and of course paid account only as well.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Notably an alphanumeric sender ID has at least one alphabetic character in it, otherwise they are indistinguishable from phone numbers. A short code is indeed a different concept, it is for high volume messaging and comes with an application process and a higher fee. You can read more about short codes here: https://www.twilio.com/sms/short-codes